# Associativity math: (a + b) + c != a + (b + c)

Tags: c#, .net, math, numeric

Recently I was going through an [old blog post by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/) 
in which, while writing about associativity he mentions that in C#, `(a + b) + c` is not equivalent to `a + (b + c)` for certain values of a, b, c.

I am not able to figure out for **what types and range of arithmetic values** might that hold true and why.

Comment: Probably floating points values...

Comment: FWIW, this issue is not C# specific. Floating point math as implemented in hardware is not exactly associative. Indeed, it's not only hardware but any floating point implementation conforming to IEEE 754. If you need associativity for real-like numbers you need to invent your own format (and probably hire a mathematician in the process)

Comment: @slebetman Any system that uses a fixed number of significant digits will be not associative. If we use a single significant digit for example, rounding after each operation, we have: (1 + 0.5) + 0.5 == 1.5 (rounded to 2) + 0.5 == 2.5 (rounded to 3) == 3, while 1 + (0.5 + 0.5) == 1 + 1 == 2. IEEE 754 simply uses binary digits instead of decimal digits with a fixed number of significant digits (the mantissa)

Comment: @slebetman: Rational arithmetic would do the trick, no mathematician required.

Comment: @Mehrdad: xanatos's comment above shows why a mathematician is needed. Turns out it's not possible but I as an engineer didn't know that.

Comment: @slebetman: I think you missed the fact that he was talking about a fixed number of digits whereas I wasn't. (Rational arithmetic means you represent every number as a ratio of two integers, which can be arbitrary-precision.) You really don't need a mathematician for this...

Comment: @Mehrdad You would need rational arithmetic with infinite digits (so "real world" rational arithmetic)

Comment: @xanatos: Not quite -- that's only if you want to go beyond basic arithmetic (`+ - * /`), which would then usually be a library feature rather than a language feature. For basic arithmetic in the language, you don't. In fact the whole *point* of representing numbers as rationals is so you don't need to store an infinite number of digits for basic arithmetic, since the rationals are closed under basic arithmetic. (This is a nontrivial observation; if it's not obvious at first glance that's normal.)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: How is a C# question a duplicate of a C question...?

Comment: read this [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714) [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) [Floating point addition is not associative](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5380)

Comment: @Mehrdad this is related to the property of floating-point arithmetic, which is language agnostic

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: ...what? Just because the answer (and reason) happens to be the same doesn't mean the question is a duplicate! Heck, the OP didn't even say anything about floating-point. How in the world would his question be a duplicate of a question about floating-point?! I wish I could downvote comments...

Comment: @Mehrdad: If the answer and reason is the same then it's a duplicate even though the question is worded differently. The concept of duplicates is so that questions that are worded differently but have the same answer should point to a single answer.

Comment: @slebetman: I don't think you understand what closing as "duplicate" means? The description under the close reason literally says, *"This question has been asked before*". The question you linked to is **not** just a "different wording" of this question. It's an entirely different question, about a very different language, that merely happens to have the same answer. If the *answer* is a duplicate it does not logically follow that "the question has been asked before".

Comment: @Mehrdad: That's merely an A/B problem. This question (why floating point additions are not associative) has been asked before.

Comment: @Mehrdad: it has been discussed multiple times on Meta that if the answers are duplicate then the question is as well. That's the whole point of duplicates, actually: to have multiple different questions point to the same answer. Having multiple questions means that it will be easier to find, because different people formulate the question differently or the question shows up in different contexts (e.g. in this example C and C#). Having a single answer means that effort is focused in a single place and not scattered around the system.

Comment: @Mehrdad With infinite digits I meant non-fixed digits... If you have 8 bits for the denominator, so 0-255 (unsigned), then `1/2 + 1/255` can't be represented exactly (the new denominator would be 510, that is outside the range)... You have to round it in some way. I'm not sure if this rounding (depending on how it is done) can/will make it non-associative.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I see. Would you have a link to the Meta post?

Comment: @xanatos: If by "infinite" you meant "unbounded" then I have to ask: did you [read my 2nd comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004190/c-sharp-associativity-math-a-b-c-a-b-c?noredirect=1#comment51912729_32004190)? I was trying to explain to slebetman exactly the same thing that you're now trying to convey to me lol.

Comment: @Mehrdad No, I hadn't... We say the same thing...

Answer (score 78, accepted):

On the range of the `double` type:

```
double dbl1 = (double.MinValue + double.MaxValue) + double.MaxValue;
double dbl2 = double.MinValue + (double.MaxValue + double.MaxValue);
```

The first one is `double.MaxValue`, the second one is `double.Infinity`

On the precision of the `double` type:

```
double dbl1 = (double.MinValue + double.MaxValue) + double.Epsilon;
double dbl2 = double.MinValue + (double.MaxValue + double.Epsilon);
```

Now `dbl1 == double.Epsilon`, while `dbl2 == 0`.

And on literally reading the question :-)

In `checked` mode:

```
checked
{
    int i1 = (int.MinValue + int.MaxValue) + int.MaxValue;
}
```

`i1` is `int.MaxValue`

```
checked
{
    int temp = int.MaxValue;
    int i2 = int.MinValue + (temp + temp);
}
```

(note the use of the `temp` variable, otherwise the compiler will give an error directly... Technically even this would be a different result :-) Compiles correctly vs doesn't compile)

this throws an `OverflowException`... The results are different :-) (`int.MaxValue` vs `Exception`)

Comment: A very good answer; however it addresses a limitation of the _range_ of the datatype, while I would guess that the question is more related to the _accuracy_ of the datatype within its range.

Comment: @Codor Added an example on precision.

Comment: Perhaps the reason that this is so hard to understand is that the associative and other properties of numbers is theoretical. They apply ONLY when the range is UNBOUNDED, whether talking about integers or real numbers. So if we were to use every atom in the universe to represent a decimal digit, for example, we would be working with a bounded system of numbers, for which the associative and similar properties would not apply.

Answer (score 14):

one example

```
a = 1e-30
b = 1e+30
c = -1e+30
```

Comment: another more surprising example is `(0.1+0.2)+0.3` and `0.1+(0.2+0.3)` http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5380

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc: This kind of precision-based errors are implementation-dependent. You may get different results on Win7 running VS and on Linux running Mono, for instance. You may even get no error at all.

Comment: @legrojan unless double precison math is done internally with higher precision

Comment: strictly speaking kind of example I have presented is also implementation defined. There could be some implementation where example would hold - for example using Rational numbers as type.

Answer (score 8):

Extending on the other answers which show how with extremes of small and large numbers you get a different result, here's an example where floating point with realistic normal numbers gives you a different answer.

In this case, instead of using numbers at the extreme limits of precision I simply do a lot of additions. The difference is between doing `(((...(((a+b)+c)+d)+e)...` or `...(((a+b)+(c+d))+((e+f)+(g+h)))+...`

I'm using python here, but you will probably get the same results if you write this in C#. First create a list of a million values, all of which are 0.1. Add them up from the left and you see the rounding errors become significant:

```
>>> numbers = [0.1]*1000000
>>> sum(numbers)
100000.00000133288
```

Now add them again, but this time add them in pairs (there are much more efficient ways to do this that use less intermediate storage, but I kept the implementation simple here):

```
>>> def pair_sum(numbers):
    if len(numbers)==1:
        return numbers[0]
    if len(numbers)%2:
        numbers.append(0)
    return pair_sum([a+b for a,b in zip(numbers[::2], numbers[1::2])])

>>> pair_sum(numbers)
100000.0
```

This time any rounding errors are minimised.

*Edit* for completeness, here's a more efficient but less easy to follow implementation of a pairwise sum. It gives the same answer as the `pair_sum()` above:

```
def pair_sum(seq):
    tmp = []
    for i,v in enumerate(seq):
        if i&1:
            tmp[-1] = tmp[-1] + v
            i = i + 1
            n = i & -i
            while n > 2:
                t = tmp.pop(-1)
                tmp[-1] = tmp[-1] + t
                n >>= 1
        else:
            tmp.append(v)
    while len(tmp) > 1:
        t = tmp.pop(-1)
        tmp[-1] = tmp[-1] + t
    return tmp[0]
```

And here's the simple pair_sum written in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static double pair_sum(double[] numbers)
        {
            if (numbers.Length==1)
            {
                return numbers[0];
            }
            var new_numbers = new double[(numbers.Length + 1) / 2];
            for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i += 2) {
                new_numbers[i / 2] = numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1];
            }
            if (numbers.Length%2 != 0)
            {
                new_numbers[new_numbers.Length - 1] = numbers[numbers.Length-1];
            }
            return pair_sum(new_numbers);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var numbers = new double[1000000];
            for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) numbers[i] = 0.1;
            Console.WriteLine(numbers.Sum());
            Console.WriteLine(pair_sum(numbers));
        }
    }
}
```

with output:

```
100000.000001333
100000
```

Answer (score 4):

This stems from the fact that ordinary value types (int, long, etc.) are stored using a fixed amount of bytes. Overflow is thus possible, when the sum of two values exceeds the byte storage capacity.

In C#, one may use [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.100).aspx) to avoid this kind of issue. BigInteger's are arbitrary in size and therefore do not create overflows.

BigInteger is only available from .NET 4.0 and above (VS 2010+).

Comment: integer addition in finite field (for example 32 bit arithmetic) is associative

Comment: @LukaRahne Not if at least one of the individual sums exceeds the 32 (as per your example) bit limit. In that case, as xanatos showed above, one gets into trouble.

Comment: that happens in case that one conducts `checked` operations. By default operations are not checked against overflows and in such case associative law holds.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is `(a + b) + c == a + (b + c)` mathematically, but not necessarily computationally.

Remembering that computers really work in binary, even simple decimals can result in roundoff errors when converted to internal format.

Depending on the language, even addition can incur roundoff errors, and in the above example, the roundoff error in `a+b` may differ from that in `b+c`.

One surprising offender is JavaScript: `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`. The roundoff error is a long way down the decimal, but real and problematic.

It’s a general principal that you reduce roundoff error by adding the small parts first. This way they can accumulate before being overwhelmed by the larger number.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of similar examples:

```
static void A(string s, int i, int j)
{
  var test1 = (s + i) + j;
  var test2 = s + (i + j);
  var testX = s + i + j;
}
```

Here `A("Hello", 3, 5)` leads to `test1` and `testX` being equal to `"Hello35"`, while `test2` will be `"Hello8"`.

And:

```
static void B(int i, int j, long k)
{
  var test1 = (i + j) + k;
  var test2 = i + (j + k);
  var testX = i + j + k;
}
```

Here `B(2000000000, 2000000000, 42L)` leads to `test1` and `testX` being equal to `-294967254L` in usual `unchecked` mode, while `test2` becomes `4000000042L`.

Answer (score 0):

On the same blog in comments i found this, what is the meaning of thid "^" symbol in C#

a = 10 ^ x

b = -a

c = 5

(a+b) + c == 5

a + (b+c) == 0